# UINavigationBar left button item jumps right by some pixels strange behavior

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, layout, uinavigationbar

I am a bit confused with this behaviour, but I can't fix it for now and I need help.

I have controller which I wrap into `UINavigationController`

```
- (void) buttonPressed {

    NewKeyInformationViewController *addKeyViewController = [[NewKeyInformationViewController alloc]initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([NewKeyInformationViewController class]) bundle:nil];
    addKeyViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:addKeyViewController];
    navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;
    [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Right after presentation animation ends, I see that leftBarButtonItem jumps to the right.

I can see this behavior on iOS 8.4 ( iOS 7.1 works well )

**Information:**

I add leftBarButtonItem programmatically:

// NewKeyInformationViewController.m

```
- (void)addCloseButton {
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(closeButtonPressed:)];
}

- (void)closeButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self addCloseButton];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"some title";
    // and many items here
}
```

**Thoughts**:

I didn't understand this behavior, because my presentation style ( controller wrapped into navigation controller and this sandwich presented as modal )
 doesn't rely on anything around it as environment ( controller that presenting this modal controller, for example )

Comment: Are you adding a leftBarButtonItem programmatically to the new controller?

Comment: @jrisberg, yes, I updated post with related code

Comment: I saw this issue once, the problem ended up being that I was adding my custom button in `viewWillAppear`, which is too late though you seem to be using viewDidLoad as you should be. The system provided button was in a slightly different place (a few pixels as you mention) and it was being replaced by my custom button after it had come on screen. Try hiding your button until it's added to the nav bar.

Comment: Are you still having a problem with this? I've tried a basic setup, presenting the `UINavigationController` as you are - and all is ok. Do you have anything else in the `UINavigationItem`?

Comment: @GavinHope, yes, I still have a troubles with it. Also, I updated post. ( I setup `navigationItem.title` with left bar item

Comment: @gaussblurinc - I'll take another look. I see that you've updated the question with **Thoughts** at the end... what is the view hierarchy for the *presenting* view controller? That is, in the `buttonPressed` method when ` [self presentViewController:navigationController animated:YES completion:nil];` is called, is that view controller already in a `UINavigationController`? A `UITabBarController`? Etc...

Comment: @GavinHope, thank you! You ask me right questions! I look up into view hierarchy thoroughly and find out that my view hierarchy was broken! Thanks!

Comment: @gaussblurinc - no problem, glad you fixed it ;)